# Mudar cor de uma linha no datatable ao marcar uma checkbox

Tags: jsf, primefaces, bootsfaces

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando o framework bootsfaces em JavaWeb.

Em uma das minhas telas tenho um datatable do bootsfaces com os valores vindos do meu Bean e uma checkbox do primefaces que auxilia na exclusão ou alteração de determinado registro.

Preciso fazer com que ao clicar em qualquer dos campos de determinado registro no datatable, o checkbox do primefaces seja acionado e a respectiva linha tenha sua cor mudada.

O código xhtml até o momento:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="frm">
            <b:dataTable value="#{beanUsuario.usuarios}" style="width: 100%; " id="tabelaUsuario"
                         page-length="5" page-length-menu="5,10,20,50,100" var="usuario"
                         widgetVar="usuario" customLangUrl="json/Portuguese-Brasil.json">
                <b:dataTableColumn header-style="text-align:center;
                                   border-right:none;" content-style="border:none; text-align:center;" label="Nome" >
                    <label for="check#{usuario.nome}">
                        #{usuario.nome}
                    </label>
                </b:dataTableColumn>
                <b:dataTableColumn header-style="text-align:center;" content-style="border:none; text-align:center;" label="Email">
                    <label for="check#{usuario.nome}">
                        #{usuario.email}
                    </label>
                </b:dataTableColumn>
                <b:dataTableColumn header-style="text-align:center;" content-style="border:none; text-align:center;" label="Endereço">
                    <label for="check#{usuario.nome}">
                        #{usuario.endereco}
                    </label>
                </b:dataTableColumn>
                <b:dataTableColumn header-style="text-align:center;" content-style="border:none; text-align:center;" label="Telefone">
                    <label for="check#{usuario.nome}">
                        #{usuario.telefone}
                    </label>
                </b:dataTableColumn>

                <b:dataTableColumn label="Check box Prime" header-style="text-align:center;" content-style="border:none; text-align:center;" >
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="check#{usuario.nome}">
                        <p:ajax listener="#{beanUsuario.selecionaUsuario(usuario.nome)}" /> 
                    </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </b:dataTableColumn>
            </b:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Aqui está meu Bean:

```
package com.controller.usuario;

import com.model.usuario.Usuario;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

@Named(value = "beanUsuario")
@RequestScoped
public class BeanUsuario implements Serializable {

    private Usuario usuario;
    private Usuario usuarioSelecionado;
    private List<Usuario> usuarios;



    public BeanUsuario() {
        usuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
        usuario = new Usuario();

        teste = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            Usuario u = new Usuario();

            u.setDescricao("ALGO" + i);
            u.setEmail("usuario@gmail.com");
            u.setEndereco("estrada" + 1);
            u.setTelefone(i);
            u.setNome("user" + i);
            u.setTelefone(1232 + i);

            usuarios.add(u);
        }

    }


    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }



    public List<Usuario> getUsuarios() {
        return usuarios;
    }

    public void setUsuarios(List<Usuario> usuarios) {
        this.usuarios = usuarios;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(English version below - please apologize my bad Portuguese).

Parece que você descobriu uma característica faltando do BootsFaces. No entanto, se você pode fazer sem a checkbox do PrimeFaces, use os atributos `select="true"` e `selectionMode="multiple"`. Eles permitem que você selecione uma única linha. Você também pode chamar um método usando AJAX quando a linha é selecionada.

It seems you've discovered a missing feature of BootsFaces. However, if you can do without the PrimeFaces checkbox, use the attributes `select="true"` and `selectionMode="multiple"`. They allow you to select a single row. You can also call a method using AJAX when the row is selected.

Comment: Sua solução resolveu parcialmente o meu problema, pois ao usar esses elementos do datatable a cor da linha é mudada porém o ajax do "onSelect" não é acionado. O engraçado é que ao usar o p:selectBooleanCheckbox do primefaces ele executa exatamente a função solicitada.

Comment: Poderia me das mais algumas dicas de como o "onSelect" funciona?

Comment: Consegui fazer com que a função seja chamada pelo "onSelect" . Ao invés de fazer a chamada do método desse jeito:  onselect="#{beanUsuario.selecionaUsuario(usuario.nome)}" fiz assim :  onselect="ajax:beanUsuario.selecionaUsuario(usuario.nome);" como explicado no site do bootsfaces

Comment: Talvez devêssemos melhorar isso, também. É um alçapão comum. Eu decidi deliberadamente adicionar AJAX aos métodos de retorno de chamada existentes do JavaScript. Mas o padrão JSF faz um pouco diferente, muitos desenvolvedores tentam transmitir o método como expressão EL. ---

Maybe we should improve this, too. It's a common trapdoor. I deliberately decided to add AJAX to existing JavaScript callback methods. But standard JSF does it a bit different, so many developers try to pass the method as EL expression.

Comment: https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/835 e https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/836.